# Convert constants from vb to c#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

There are a bunch of constants like vbTab in VB.Net, is there corresponding one in C# ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is not an exact corresponding set of constants oriented for C#.  Certain constants are simply represented in string form (e.g., `"\t"` for `vbTab`).

I would suggest **not** referencing the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly to use those constants.  That namespace mainly exists to support migration of legacy VB6 applications.

Comment: Just wanted to throw in `System.Environment.NewLine` as a substitute for `vbCrLf`; other than that one, just use string literals (`\n \t \r` etc.).

Comment: Pedantic, I know, but I wouldn't use `System.Environment.NewLine` as a substitute for `vbCrLf`.  vbCrLf is explicitly a CR-LF (i.e. "\r\n").  System.Environment.NewLine is an environment-specific newline string - it's the same as vbCrLf on Windows, but may not be on other platforms e.g. when using Mono on a non-Windows platform.

Comment: @Cory I was porting some VB.NET code with an automatic conversion tool and used your method to create the following line of code: private const String vbCrLf = "\r\n"